# In Pandas, how can I perform the .diff() method to numerical values only in a column that also contains NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a Pandas dataset and I would like to calculate the difference of a column element compared with another element of the same column. In order to do so, the most intuitive method to apply is [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

So far, so good. The problem is that my column contains `nan` values without a specific order pattern, like the following example with a column named `col`:

```py
  | col |
  |-----|
0 |  1  |
1 | NaN |
2 |  3  |
3 |  4  |
4 | NaN |
5 | NaN |
6 | 10  |
7 | NaN |
8 | 13  |
```

What I would like to do is to apply the `.diff()` method **only to the preceding numerical values of the column**, such that the expected answer is:

```py
  | col |
  |-----|
0 | NaN |
1 | NaN |
2 |  2  |
3 |  1  |
4 | NaN |
5 | NaN |
6 |  6  |
7 | NaN |
8 |  3  |
```

Had it been a periodic order of the `nan` values, I could have used the `periods` parameter of the `.diff()` method, as explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). However, given that the `nan` values appear in a random order, I was wondering how this could be done?

Comment: If you like my answer below, feel free to make it the accpeted answer :) thank you. Otherwise please let me know if it is unclear and I can edit the answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `dropna` and set up a temporary variable, and `reindex` like this:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, 13]})
idx = df.index  # create index from original data
tmp = df.dropna()  # drop nan rows
tmp.diff().reindex(idx)  # reindex to original index
>>>
  | col |
  |-----|
0 | NaN |
1 | NaN |
2 |  2  |
3 |  1  |
4 | NaN |
5 | NaN |
6 |  6  |
7 | NaN |
8 |  3  |
```